# Synchronous vs Asynchronous in Microservice pattern

Tags: asynchronous, microservices, synchronous

What is the meaning of Synchronous and Asynchronous in general?

What are the use of Synchronous and Asynchronous communication in microservice? When to use synchronous and when to use Asynchronous.

Please explain with example thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you researched so far? Are you confused about anything specific?

Comment: I watched some videos on yt and get to know how to use them but i need to know what is synchronous and asynchronous and what specific situation when we can differentiate that which one is better to use.(communication between two microservices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under synchronous, the communication between components is live all the time. An example would be a service making a GET/ POST call and waiting for the response to proceed to the immediate next step.

Asynchronous meaning one component does not wait for the other components to react. An example would be a service publishing message to a Kafka topic. The service which creates the event does not know when the clients will consume it.

I would start thinking about the application end-user use case to decide when I should use what.

Comment: So, we can say synchronous means "happens at a same time" and Asynchronous means "doesn't happens at same time"?